# Display Text and Custom Toggle in same line

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm trying to develop a custom toggle button and attache a text before it. I want the text and toggle to be in the same line. But, the text is coming in one line and the toggle in other.

The working code: https://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/x6v1nevw/1/

When i add the style `display:inline-block;` then the shape of the toggle circle is getting disturbed. I'm trying to develop this in Angular2 as a component.
The woking code in Angular2:http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZnrnJbSyFAp5c6Z0V7T?p=preview

HTML code:

```
   <div style="display:inline;">  
    Toggle1:
    <div class="onoffswitch" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked >
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline;">
    Toggle2:
    <div class="onoffswitch" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch1" >
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch1">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 50px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 22px; padding: 0; line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 10px; color: white; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "";//ON
    padding-left: 8px;
    background-color: lightgreen; 
    color: pink;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "";//OFF
    padding-right: 6px;
    background-color: red; 
    color: #F9FAFB;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 20px; margin: 0px;
    background: #F9FAFB;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 30px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    box-shadow: 0.276px 0.961px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked  + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;

}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onoffswitch class is applied to a div element, which by default has a display value of 'block'. Block elements by default will be displayed on their own line.

Add this style to the onoffswitch class:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Hi, when i add the display:inline-block; the circle of the toggle button is getting out of shape. I've attached a plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZnrnJbSyFAp5c6Z0V7T?p=preview . I'm developing the component in Angular2 to reuse it.